# Issue on zoom VideoView

Tags: android, video

I'm struggling with this video issue for a while. I thought you may have some ideas to help me.

So I'm having this VideoView in a frame layout and on top I have a ToggleButton to make zoom and came back from zoom.

```
<CustomVideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" >
</CustomVideoView>
```

and I have a video 480x360 and I thought that when making zoom in portrait, I will resize it at the screen height and the calculated width, based on the video ratio.(in landscape otherwise).

I have extended VideoView to CustomVideoView using:

```
    public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {

    protected int _overrideWidth = 480;

    protected int _overrideHeight = 360;

    public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
    }

    public void resizeVideo(int width, int height) {
        _overrideHeight = height;
        _overrideWidth = width;
        // not sure whether it is useful or not but safe to do so
        getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height); 
        requestLayout();
        invalidate(); // very important, so that onMeasure will be triggered
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        setMeasuredDimension(_overrideWidth, _overrideHeight);
    }
}
```

on some devices the trick works fine, but on Google Nexus with 4.0.3 it stretches the video to the screen and on Galaxy S 2.3.3 it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be dependent on underlying native code, that is vendor (Samsung in your case) used for SurfaceView (and so on VideoView) realisation. Also MediaPlayer, which is part of VideoView too, can have device-specific realisation (also native), and it can affect all VideoView behavior.

Comment: so I can't do anything about it? if it is native it seems the zoom will never work the same on all devices? What about Nexus , this shouldn't have any custom native code?

Comment: I've just compared VideoView from 2.2 with one from 4.0.3 and there same differences...can they be the ones causing different behavior? http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/VideoView.java/?v=diff&id2=2.2_r1.1

Comment: No, in 4.0.3 they just have added some more MediaPlayer states and provided new Controller. So - I can say nothing about native code.

Comment: Actually, afaik, for Android 2.x there were 2 or 3 different realisations of MediaPlayer, each with it's own set of bugs. It was hard to overcome most of issues, when I was writing TV application.

Can you try not to use `getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);`, but `setSizeFromLayout()`. It can be helpful, cause whaen you're doing `onMeasure()`, view internal size should be updated.

Comment: same results on Google Nexus with setSizeFromLayout():( video is stretched , not zoomed